# In Moose, how do I create a rw proxy attribute for another rw attribute

Tags: perl, moose

In a Moose class I have a rw attribute referring to a position within a declared list.

```perl
has 'option_index' => (
  isa => 'Int',
  is => 'rw',
);

my $options = [qw(one two three)];

has 'option' => (
  is => 'rw',
  # ???
  # should take 'one' and set option_index to 0, ...
  # should return $options->[$self->option_index]
);
```

I want to create a proxy attribute, that gets the value at option_index of the list and sets option_index to the position where the argument is found.

I can create a simple sub that does that, but I would want to get into the benefit of Moose type checking and therefore declare it as an attribute.

Can this be done?

- I don't care for the implementation, only for the Moose set up and
- option_index has to remain

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a [trigger function](https://metacpan.org/dist/Moose/view/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod#Triggers):

```
package Foo;
use Moose;

has 'option_index' => (
  isa => 'Int',
  is => 'rw',
  default => 0,
);

my $options = [qw(one two three)];

has 'option' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str',
    trigger => \&_set_option_trigger,
);


sub _set_option_trigger {
    my ( $self, $new_value, $old_value ) = @_;

    for my $idx (0..$#$options) {
        if ($options->[$idx] eq $new_value) {
            $self->option_index($idx);
            return;
        }
    }
    die "Unknown option '$new_value'";
}

no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $foo = Foo->new();
$foo->option('three');
say "Option is: ", $foo->option;
say "Option index is : ", $foo->option_index;
$foo->option('four');
```

**Output**:

```
Option is: three
Option index is : 2
Unknown option 'four' at ./p.pl line 30.
```

**Edit**:

To have the `option` attribute have a default value that is determined from the `option_index` attribute, you can try add `lazy` and a `default` sub like this:

```
has 'option' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str',
    lazy => 1,
    default => sub { my $self = shift; $options->[$self->option_index] },
    trigger => \&_set_option_trigger,
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Håkon, for the reply. Unfortunately this relies on option to be set. If only option_index is set, option returns undef. Probably, one could have another trigger at option_index, but it does not strike me as very elegant...

Comment: @Jan See my updated answer. Does it help you?

Comment: it certainly does! I wonder if it is the leanest implementation, but is certainly better than my status quo :)